# sign of values of an integer polynomial on roots of unity

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $n>0$ be an even integer divisible by $4$

Let $R(t)=r_0+r_1t+ \cdots + r_{n-1}t^{n-1}$

be a polynomial with nonzero integer coefficients in $\{-1,1\}$
such that

$R(\omega)$ is a nonzero integer for all complex $\omega$ $\notin$ $\{-1,1\}$
such that
$$
\omega^n=1
$$

Can we deduce that all these integers $R(\omega)$ have the same sign ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+ \ldots + x^{n-1})-2x^{n/2}$.

EDIT: It is customary after someone answers your question not to change the question. As it happens, the slightest possible change to my answer *still* provides an answer to the latest version of your question (at the time of this edit). The little icon produced for my username (produced completely randomly as it happens) reflects my opinion of the practice of changing the question after it has been answered.

Comment: Let $C=circ(r_0,r_1, \ldots ,r_{n-1})$ be the circulant matrix
with first row $r_0, \ldots ,r_{n-1}$. The $R(\omega)$ are the
eigenvalues of $C$.
We may consider the special case when $C$ is orthogonal in order
to see different signs taken by the eigenvalues.


Comment: @unknown mannekin pisse:  Assume that $C$ is also a Hadamard matrix.  I am afraid not to yet understand why
when the circulant matrix $C$
is symmetric or `close to` be symmetric, the associated `quadratic form`  $Q$ transforming
 $x \to x^T Cx$  (or something alike when $C$
is not symmetric) must have  a very special signature, of the type $(1,*)$ or $(-1,*)$, (that forces $n=4$)
while `normally`  (for more non-circulant Hadamard's) the signature should be of the type
$ ((n+\sqrt{n})/2,(n-\sqrt{n})/2)$.

